# What obligation does an HOA attorney have to follow HOA rules?

Tags: hoa

A rule was passed requiring pre-approve attorney engagements to be approved at meeting so that the public can see what is being done and prevent board members from unilaterally engaging the attorney.

Board members are engaging the attorney without pre-approval.  The attorney was notified of the rule last week.

Is there any forcing function that compels the Florida attorney to follow the rules?

Comment: "Is there any forcing function that compels the Florida attorney to follow the rules?" Not sure what you mean by a "forcing function".

Comment: Any factor that would compel behavior or exert a force